# How do i sort a dictionary by value that has tuples as values

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary that has strings as keys and tuples with two elements as values:

```
d = {"Alex": (18, 22), "Maria": (5, 11), "John": (18, 19), "Jim": (5, 8)}
```

I am trying to sort this dictionary by value but I want a descending order of `value[0]` and an ascending order of `value[1]`.

When I use:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

the output is:

```
{"Alex": (18, 22), "John": (18, 19), "Maria": (5, 11), "Jim": (5, 8)}
```

while I need it to be:

```
{"John": (18, 19), "Alex": (18, 22), "Jim": (5, 8), "Maria": (5, 11)}
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Don't name your own dictionary `dict`, it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: sorted(a.items(), key=lambda e: (-e[1][0], +e[1][1]))
Out[1]: [('John', (18, 19)), ('Alex', (18, 22)), ('Jim', (5, 8)), ('Maria', (5, 11))]
```

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what i suggested :)